# How to show route from point A to D, avoid polygons and not intersect with them?

Tags: python-3.x, gis, networkx, shapefile, fiona

User can put 2 coords(startcoord, endcoords), and after that I calculate the shortest path using A* algorithm.
Also want to validate this path, not going throw land.
So right now I need to remove those coords, and update them with new ones. 
Also have an dataset, where are all polygons of land.
So the route that Im generated need to be only on the sea and the shortest one.
Can find intersection between those points and land, but any idea how to find the nearset point in the sea?

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to provide you with a good answer.  For starters you should provide information about your data structures and your path-finding algorithm.

Comment: @John I have an dataset, lets say when there are some polygons of the land. path-find algorithm that i'm using its same as A* algorithm....The main focus is how to avoid the coordinates that are going throw land?
Firstly I check each segment if intersect with each polygon, if yes i saved those coords in list and try again to get new coords, but this take a lot of time,
also i have tried to create visibility graph with polygons that I have, but Im getting memory error.. So any idea/suggestion?

Comment: Is there a way that you can just remove the "land" polygons from your dataset prior to running your pathfinding algorithm?

Comment: @John yes, I can make the changes there too...